# Cant remove the nut holding the wiper motor to the wiper transmission

Tags: chevrolet, windshield-wipers

I am having an issue where I needed to replace my windshield wiper motor, and I got down to it where I now have access to the transmission and the motor. The linkage to the transmission is held together by a nut, but that nut is not wanting to budge. And the main issue is Im focusing more effort in holding the transmission still vs taking the nut off. Any suggestions?

[image: The wiper blade motor]

[image: The wiper blade transmission with the nut that serves as linkage]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been done, I placed a 2x4 under the transmission (drivebar) after forcing the transmission into the down position to create a leverage.

Comment: Good deal. All you needed to do was to stop the arm from moving, which you did. Easy-peasy. Don't forget to select this as your answer (probably take two days to allow it).

Comment: Forcing the transmission like that has been known to break the teeth on the gears... which is why I use the adjustable....

Comment: The gears in my motor were stripped which was why I was replacing the motor.

Comment: @SolarMike Using an adjustable wrench instead of a socket wrench should not make a different. The nut would still move the transmission at least until it was loose enough to not put pressure on the linkage which was the issue. Not the tool. So I had to force the transmission into the down gear and use leverage. There was no way around that.

Comment: If you had read my original answer properly, you would have recognized that I said "holding the arm with the adjustable and using a good quality socket or spanner on the nut", holding the arm with the adjustable prevents the damage to the gears as the force is applied by the adjustable and the socket / spanner. Done this job many times and never stripped or broken gears...

Comment: Oh, I could not find a way to hold it like that. But I did wedge it with the 2x4, either way I had to reset it manually because the gears in the motor wore out and in order for it to be in a place I could wedge it I had no choice to do it myself.